# Can I diff more than one file at a time using subversion and Beyond Compare?

Tags: svn, diff, beyondcompare, 3-way-merge

So, I've successfully figured out how to do a simple diff and a 3 way merge with command-line subversion and Beyond Compare 3 using Windows 7. Thank you, stackoverflow.

However, I frequently have lots of files that I change in between commits, i.e. an html file, css file and javascript file all related to the same bug fix. When I'm using the built in svn diff, I can just type "svn di" and it will show me a list of all the diffs in all the files. Is there a way to trigger this type of functionality with Beyond Compare 3?

At the moment, when I type "svn di", it will send the first file to Beyond Compare, and when I'm done reviewing the changes, I close the beyond compare window, and the diff ends. There's no way for me to diff the other files without typing in each name manually. (And sometimes I can't remember all the ones I've changed... basically, it gets really messy.)

Is this even possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not what you're looking, but TortoiseSVN integrated with Beyond Compare 3 works a treat for this sort of operation. My workflow after an svn update is typically:

1. TortoiseSVN > Check For Modifications | Commit
2. Review each modification by double-click/compare with base ([integrated with BC3](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=3699))
3. Update svn log based on diff output shown in BC3.

The reason why this may suit your task is that you can select all modified files (Ctrl+A), then double-click/compare with base, and BC3 will load up all the diffs at once in separate tabs.

You might also be able to achieve this from the [command line](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-basics) (untested).

Comment: this works beautifully, as far as I can tell without using it for a week. You are my favorite person ever :D I can't award the bounty for another 7 hours, though.

Comment: Yep that's exactly how I worked too, with TortoiseSVN and BC3. It was fantastic! Now I'm somewhere else and using VSS :/

Answer (score 0):

My exposioure to Beyond Compare has only been through collueages' use (so I do not know it very well), but you might want to try the [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) comparision tool instead (free, GPL) which is really excellent. I am not aware of any svn integration problems other than the [wrapper issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803881/how-to-set-kdiff3-as-merge-tool-for-svn/4804842#4804842) mentioned here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but at this point I'm looking for a solution involving Beyond Compare specifically.